# Hide parts of a book keeping section counters

Tags: sectioning

I have a document source with numbered sections and additional counters. Now I want to print only one section and a part of the appendice, keeping the original section numbers and counter values. 
Practically, I want latex to parse the whole source but not output parts of it. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{do not print}

For now, this section is not intended for printing

\section{do print}

But only this one

\appendix

\section{related to section 1}

suppress this one

\section{related to section 2}

Print this

\end{document}
```

My document should look like this:

### 2 do print

But only print this one

### B related to section 2

Print this

Is there a possibility to temporarily hide sections keeping the numbering?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** You could tweak the numbers by using `\setcounter{section}{1}` just before `section{do print}` and hide the content of other unwanted sections in the suitable environments of one of the packages `comment` or `version` or `versions`. (If section 1 is short enough it would suffice to comment it out).

**Solution 2:** A much better way would be to put the content of either section in separate files that you `\include{}` in the main file. With the additional command  `\includeonly{sect2, appb}` in preamble, you would automatically get what you want. The overhead seems larger than in solution 1, but is much more efficient as soon as the content grows.

By the way, `\include` adds a `\clearpage` before the file content, which is fine for a `\chapter` in `book` class but possibly unwanted for `\section` in `article` class. A workaround is as follows. Put in the preamble :

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
 \makeatletter
 \let\includenobreak=\include
 \let\@includenobreak=\@include
 \patchcmd{\@includenobreak}{\clearpage}{}{}{}
 \patchcmd{\includenobreak}{\@include}
{\@includenobreak}{}{}
 \makeatother
```

and use `\includenobreak` instead of `\include`.

**EDIT:** explicit implementation of solution 2 (based on `\include` and `\includeonly`
I provide a self-contained file by including dummy  chapters 1 and 2  as `filecontents`.

```
%--------------chapters--------
\begin{filecontents*}{chap1}
\chapter{A first chapter}
At the beginning of chapter \thechapter, testcounter = \thetestcounter\par
The first chapter content...\par
\addtocounter{testcounter}{1}
At the end of chapter \thechapter, testcounter = \thetestcounter
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap2}
\chapter{A second chapter}
At the beginning of chapter \thechapter, testcounter = \thetestcounter\par
The second chapter content...\par
\addtocounter{testcounter}{2}
At the end of chapter \thechapter, testcounter = \thetestcounter
\end{filecontents*}

%--------------main.tex--------
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\includeonly{chap2}
\newcounter{testcounter}
\begin{document}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}
```

With this strategy, the compilation without `\includeonly{chap2}` creates `chapter1.aux` and `chapter2.aux` (both included by `main.aux`) containing respectively (among others)

```
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{testcounter}{1}
```

and

```
 \setcounter{chapter}{2}
  \setcounter{testcounter}{3}
```

The result without `\includeonly{chap2}`is:
[image]
and when using this command one gets exactly the same second page, demonstrating that the values of the counters (both standard and custom)  are actually automatically conserved.

Note: The options added in `\documentclass` are for visualization purpose only.